# Regex to allow only numbers and +, -, () for number phone

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
[RegularExpression("^([0-9 .()-+)$", ErrorMessage = CommonConstants.PhoneError)]

public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

I have a PhoneNumber field. With this field I want to give a permission for user, just type number or +,-,),(.
How can I have a RegularExpression ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex has an unterminated character group (`[` with no `]`). You want something like this:

```
^([\d() +-]+)$
```

Note the order of `+` and `-` - `-` is a range indicator, so it needs to be first, last, or escaped (as in `\-`).

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/jV3zF5/1).

Comment: thank you so much.
my expectation like this
+84933932171 or
84-933932171

Comment: @NguyễnXuânHoàng Glad to help! Please remember to accept an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your supporting helped me